# Unhandled Exception: type 'Future<dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'String' : Flutter Exception

Tags: flutter, dart

I am getting this error while calling the post method.

Any help would be appreciated. Trying since 3 days.

```
    await Api_Manager().maaxusMiniReg(
    address: widget.address.toString(),
    amount: widget.amount.toString(),
    business_name: widget.agencyName.toString(),
    app_id: int.parse(widget.service_id),
    gst: widget.gst.toString(),
    email: widget.email.toString(),
    adhaar: widget.aadhaarlink.toString(),
    name: widget.name.toString(),
    mobile: widget.mobile.toString(),
    location: widget.location.toString(),
    pin: widget.pincode.toString(),
    razorpay_payment_id: response.paymentId!.toString(),
    user_id: int.parse(widget.userId),
    district: widget.districk.toString(),
    document: '',
    merchant_total: amount.toString(),
    merchant_order_id: '');
```

Comment: Which line is throwing the error?

Comment: While calling the post method

Comment: Dont kno which line is making..

Comment: you are getting all values from widget. but now the amount in last amount.toString(), is there any change?

Comment: No actually i am assigning the amount value from widget to a variable.

Comment: you need to share more info related to your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to your Model maaxumMiniRg
Then There you need to do this :

```
var  address;
  var  amount;
  var  business_name;
  var  app_id;
  var  gst;
  var  email;
   var adhaar;
  var  name;
  var  mobile;
  var  location;
  var  pin;
   var razorpay_payment_id;
   var user_id;
   var district;
   var document;
  var  merchant_total;
  var  merchant_order_id;
```

Make Variable Type **var**

Comment: No its showing the same error!

Comment: Kindly re run the project it will work